# Calling a variable in an asp.net page from Flash CS3

Tags: asp.net, flash-cs3

I have an aspx page and i have imported inside it a flash application(CS3.0) and i need to pass a variable value from the .cs file of the page to the action code can i do that ?

I can call a web page from flash code but what i need  not to call a method inside the .cs of the asp page and then get the returned value i need to pass a variable value from the page that include the flash to the flash code

thanks in advance and i hope that my question is clear for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could give ASP.NET WebMethod a try, for more information on getting Flash CS3 to interact with ASP.NET (through AJAX), see this post:

[post](http://giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=6)